# How to add scrollbar in Grid

Tags: reactjs, perfect-scrollbar

[image]

Hello,

i need help in adding a scrollbar on top, after the headers, horizontal scrollbar. thanks alot
its in react js.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
<div style={{ overflowX: 'auto',overflowY: 'auto' }}>
  ... your component
</div>
```

Also you can use this packages for scrolling;

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perfect-scrollbar
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scroll

Comment: <CardContent className={classes.content}>
          <PerfectScrollbar>
            <div className={classes.inner}>
              <Table className={classes.table}>
                <TableHead className={classes.tableHead}>
                </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
    </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </div>
          </PerfectScrollbar>
        </CardContent>

Comment: where should i add another scroll bar

Comment: You can try it https://gist.github.com/AliYmn/3d419e4ce3fe5b7a7b25f8570ffbae99

Comment: Also your scroll component should be wrap all elements to work.

Comment: Another example is https://gist.github.com/AliYmn/ba96f6f41866c8dc18ce1302a0b1f79c